# Cant make the radio button in single line

Tags: html, css, radio-button

Im having the following html for radio buttons,and I have added the css also

```
   <br/><br/>
                <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="CC" checked>
   <label for="radio1">Credit Card</label>
                    <br><br>
                        <br/><br/>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios"value="DB">
<label for="radio2">Debit Card</label>
    <br><br>
```

its css is

```
/*
  Hide radio button (the round disc)
  we will use just the label to create pushbutton effect
*/
input[type=radio] {
    display:none; 
    margin:10px;
}

/*
  Change the look'n'feel of labels (which are adjacent to radiobuttons).
  Add some margin, padding to label
*/
input[type=radio] + label {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:-2px;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    border-color: #ddd;
}
/*
 Change background color for label next to checked radio button
 to make it look like highlighted button
*/
input[type=radio]:checked + label { 
   background-image: none;
    background-color:#d0d0d0;
}
```

but the radio buttons doesnt align in one line

here is the jsfidlle http://jsfiddle.net/8ew6g/3/

heres the link http://jsfiddle.net/8ew6g/9/ [solved]

The radio button is below payment mode label,i have applied some css on it,so it wont look like a basic rabio button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**:
[This resource](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/css-radio-button-checkbox-background/) might also be useful, as it uses similar code and the result is inline.

I would suggest following this advice and then wrapping your code with the title in a `fieldset`. This will allow you to make a legend, so your code will look like this:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend><strong>Payment Mode- Select your payment mode</strong></legend>
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="all" checked>
    <label for="radio1">Credit Card</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" value="false">
    <label for="radio2">Debit Card</label>
</fieldset>
```

You will also want to add this to your CSS:

```
fieldset {
    border: none;
}
```

---

<strike>You can try this:</strike>

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="CC" checked />
            <label for="radio1">Credit<nobr/> Card</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" value="DB">
            <label for="radio2">Debit<nobr/> Card</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

in order to make sure that the line doesn't break between the two words, which happened when I tried it on your Fiddle.

Your HTML is rather muddled, particularly given the `div` elements tagged as `table` and `row`, so I am not quite sure what to make of it. I am hesitant to recommend a `table`, particularly in light of this, so maybe you should consider if there is something you could do other than using completely fake radio buttons.

Comment: See my edit for an additional alternative that features similar code to yours.

Comment: Thank you so much.i will check that

Comment: Hi please check the fiddle..I had made it correct with your help :)   http://jsfiddle.net/8ew6g/9/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the two `<Br />` tags you have between the radio buttons
and wrap the radio buttons with `<div>` and increase its width to about 180px
like:

```
      <div style="width:180px;">             
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="CC" checked>
<label for="radio1">Credit Card</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios"value="DB">
<label for="radio2">Debit Card</label>
        </div>`
```